# Authenticating outlook.com address via SAML for sharepoint login

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, saml, adfs

We are adding in ability to login to federated accounts to `SharePoint` online from our non-web application.

Generally have no issues using `SAML` to call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf for Office365 accounts.

We have a customer who used federated security, but then also allows access to some other user accounts, specifically to http://outlook.com addresses.

Since this is a federated account, passing credentials to `login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf` does not work.  I was reading some code examples which showed federated calls posting to

```
login.microsoftonline.com/GetUserRealm.srf
```

with `handler=1&login={0}`

When we do that for the http://outlook.com user account, we get back this JSON response:

```
{ "State":1, "UserState":2, "Login": "name_here@outlook.com", "FederationGlobalVersion": -1, "DomainName": "OUTLOOK.COM", "AuthURL": "https://login.live.com/login.srf?cbcxt=&popupui=&vv=&username=&mkt=&lc=&wfresh=", "NameSpaceType": "Federated", "FederationBrandName": "OUTLOOK.COM", "AuthNForwardType": 0}
```

The code examples we have see then suggest posting the SAML info to a site constructed from the AuthURL:

```
String.Format("https://{0}/adfs/services/trust/2005/usernamemixed/", adfsAuthUrl.Host);
```

That would be: https://login.live.com/adfs/services/trust/2005/usernamemixed/

However, we get a 404 error hitting that.  If we were to have called the GetUserRealm using an AD user account, we know we would have gotten a company specific AuthURL back.

Is there a different path that needs to be implemented specifically for a non-domain account (like from http://outlook.com) when trying to authenticate an `ADFS-enabled` `Office365` site?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your users to authenticate for SharePoint Online, then you should be using either a) Azure AD - get an access token and access the content via the Office 365 REST API or b) a SharePoint App in which you can choose whether to use the user context at all...in which case it still requires an access token, or, with an app-only context.  You can see lots of examples of both of these on my blog at SamlMan.wordpress.com.